# python: Why does SQLObject fail in conn.autocommit(1)?

Tags: python, psycopg2, sqlobject

In my server code, there is a call to `_SO_fetchAlternateID` (nested in some `value` call), which ultimately calls `makeConnection` in `pgconnection.py`.

This call fails on `conn.autocommit(1)`, with the error

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Here is SQLObject's (0.8.7) code:

```
def makeConnection(self):
try:
    if self.use_dsn:
        conn = self.module.connect(self.dsn)
    else:
        conn = self.module.connect(**self.dsn_dict)
except self.module.OperationalError, e:
    raise self.module.OperationalError("%s; used connection string %r" % (e, self.dsn))
if self.autoCommit:
    # psycopg2 does not have an autocommit method.
    if hasattr(conn, 'autocommit'):
        conn.autocommit(1)
return conn
```

Debugging shows that conn indeed holds a connection object, but autocommit is not a method but instead a boolean (False).

`self.module` is module 'psycopg2' (2.4.2).

Is this a configuration issue? mismatching versions?

**UPDATE:**

The cause turns out to be an incompatibility issue in psycopg2-2.4.2. Looking at the C source code, psycopg/connection.h has an integer variable unfortunately named `autocommit`. Version 2-2.4 works ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just spotted a bug. Take a look at this code:

```
def _setAutoCommit(self, conn, auto):
    # psycopg2 does not have an autocommit method.
    if hasattr(conn, 'autocommit'):
        conn.autocommit(auto)
```

It assumes that `conn` (type: `psycopg2.connection`) may not have an `autocommit` property, but when it has one, it has to be a function. It is wrong in context of `psycopg2.connection`, where [`psycopg2.connection.autocommit` is a bool](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit).

The same assumption is taken in `makeConnection` as you mentioned, and few other functions in there.

This could be fixed by changing every call like `conn.autocommit(val)` to `conn.autocommit = val`, which should be easy, even with `sed`.

Comment: I saw that code. But I also debugged the same code other computers running the same versions of SQLObject and psycopg2 where `hasattr(conn, 'autocommit')` is False.

Comment: @Ovesh That's weird. `autocommit` (just like whole `connection`) comes from C source of this module and in this source it is declared as `int` (for Python, it is `bool`, as C doesn't have any explicitly boolean type) in `psycopg/connection.h`. There's no way it wouldn't exists or be a function (if you were really using the same code - maybe some import failed or `conn` was `None`?).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it behaved the way I said it does on other machines. They are, however, running slightly different versions: 2-2.4 instead of 2-2.4.2.  There's no way for me to look at the C source on their machines, because it's already compiled into an so file.

Comment: OK, just had a look at 2-2.4 source code, and it turns out that `psycopg/connection.h` doesn't have the autocommit member. So that was the reason. Thanks for leading the way, I'll accept your answer and edit my question to reflect the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like that somewhere in the code somebody assign `autocommit = True` to the conn object.

When the interpreter reach the :

```
 conn.autocommit(1)
```

In fact it evaluates:

```
 True(1)
```

Check the content of self.dsn or self.dsn_dict, if there is not a 'autocommit' boolean key.

Comment: I looked through the SQLObject files. "dsn" and "dsn_dict" appear only in postgres/pgconnection.py (which makes sense), but autocommit was not set anywhere. I'm pretty convinced this is an incompatibility issue between the SQLObject and psycopg2 versions.